# SQL - Retain a value

Tags: sql

I have a variable that I need to retain for the rest of the visit if it changes. I am not sure how to do that in SQL

What it looks like now:

```
ID    DATE       VISIT     MARKER1
1    4-5-10       1           0
1    4-6-10       1           1
1    4-7-10       1           0
1    8-9-10       2           0
```

What I need to happen:

```
ID    DATE       VISIT     MARKER1
1    4-5-10       1           0
1    4-6-10       1           1
1    4-7-10       1           1
1    8-9-10       2           0
```

I need the change to be carried through for the rest of the visit.

Comment: What's the logic for what should be "retained"?

Comment: Sorry. Marker1 should be retained. I use retain in SAS. But It Marker1 is equal to 1 it should stay equal to 1 for the rest of the visit. I would also prefer if I created a new variable.

Comment: Per Diesel298, I agree with Tab what do you mean by retain, like change permanently in the db? Also what variable are you trying to "retain"?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Marker1=1
FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT MIN(DATE) [MinDate],Visit,ID FROM TABLE WHERE Marker1=1 GROUP BY ID,Visit
) minDate on minDate.ID=t1.ID
    AND minDate.Visit=t1.Visit
    AND t1.[DATE]>MinDate.MinDate
WHERE t1.Marker1=0
```